# Uncertainty of sum of values estimated through linear regression

Tags: regression, error-propagation

I have a continuous record of a variable X, which I want to use as a surrogate for another system value Y. I have a number of measurements of Y, which I can plot against concurrent measurements of X to get a regression between the surrogate and my actual value of interest, Y. I then use that regression to create an estimated continuous record of Y. Y represents a load being transported past a point, and what I'm generally interested in is the total load transported over some time interval, so the sum of some number of Y values.

My question: How do I define the uncertainty of my total load estimate, assuming that uncertainty primarily arises from the uncertainty in my regression?

EDIT: Per the question, yes - X is a time series, with a sampling frequency much greater than the rate of change, so autocorrelated galore. Samples of Y occur infrequently and are spread out enough that autocorrelation isn't an issue in the regression itself.

Comment: You may have additional information that is relevant and valuable. These sound like *time series* data where observations are taken sequentially over time and, perhaps, nearby observations are correlated with one another. That would have a profound effect on the correct estimate of uncertainty. Could you add to your post to fill us in on the situation?

Comment: Please only attempt to edit from the *same* account you posted with. If you have made more than one account, see the help on how to merge accounts.

Comment: The samples of Y may not be correlated, but your estimated values of Y surely will be (since the values of X are). So when you sum the estimated Y values over a time interval to get the load estimate, do you expect these values to be correlated? The answer to that question will significantly impact your estimated uncertainty.

Comment: @Dave Yes, the estimated values of Y will be very much correlated. I'm summing over contiguous intervals, so the sum will similarly be composed of correlated values.